# Issue in R package installation in SQL Server 2016 Developer edition

Tags: r, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2016 Developer edition. I am trying to install "rtweet", "text2vec" R packages into SQL Server, but it shows

> Package ‘rtweet’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried updating the version of R on SQL-server? Then try installing the packages, sometimes that works.

Comment: This answer might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721890/2026277

Comment: Is this the only error? Can you make sure all dependencies are met?

Comment: "text2vec" and "rtweet"  shows for R-3.4.0 versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you do in order to try and install the package @mzhasan? I am asking as there seems to be an issue with trying to install from the MRAN repo (which is default if you run `install.packages` with no params apart from the package name).

I have SQL Server 2016 Developer Ed. with R Services in-database and I just now successfully installed the rtweet package from the CRAN repo:

1. I opened `Rterm.exe`  as admin. You find it in the path to SQL Server R Services directories: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\R_SERVICES\bin\x64` (on my box).
2. Then I ran the the `install.packages` command for rtweet:

`install.packages("rtweet", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/", dependencies=TRUE)`

That installed quite fine! So try the CRAN repo, and see if it helps.

Niels